# Settings and Plugins 'missing'

Tags: settings

They were there previously, and the site admin is not responding. Is there anything I'm able to do?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your "site admin" has embraced Craft's "Project Config" approach which allows for config changes to be stored in version-controllable files and has probably set `allowAdminChanges` to `false` in the `config/general.php` file. This is usually a good thing, but it sounds like you are accustomed to having access to those things. For background on the whys and hows of Project Config, see the docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/project-config.html

It's best to wait until your admin gets back to you on this, but if they really are completely unreachable, if you can access that config/general.php file you should be able to delete that `allowAdminChanges` key, or set it to `true`. Beware that doing this may break any deployment workflows your developer might have set up. Ideally your site should have been built in a way that does not require you to have access to settings or plugins.